# How t to apply scope by finding id's from other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to apply scope by finding id's from another table and I don't want to use a left join.

Here is what I wanted to do:

```
scope :abcd, lambda { |value| where('where id not in (?)', List_of_other_table_ids) }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This this:

```
scope :abcd, lambda { |value| where.not(id: SomeModel.some_query.pluck(:id)) }
```

Comment: where.not(id: Model.pluck(id)) worked ...thanks for your help

Comment: `pluck(:id)` is an extra query that can be avoided just using `select`.